# Create and update documents while maintaining version history using OpenCMIS

Tags: java, alfresco, opencmis

Can someone post the OpenCMIS code necessary to create a new document and then update that document by updating its content stream? I don't want to lose the original document--I want to maintain the version history as new documents are updated. I am using Alfresco but this should be applicable to any CMIS repository.

Comment: what do you mean with "maintain the version"? Like, you want to persist or control the version number?

Comment: when I update the Document with document.setContentStream(..), it should change the version by it self and change the content of document and keep both the document in version History. I want like this

Comment: could you please post code for create document?? with version control?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In Alfresco, to create a new version, just get the Private Working Copy that is returned to you after a checkout, update the PWC's content stream, then check it back in. Alfresco will manage the versions for you. Here is an example.

```
Folder folder = (Folder) getSession().getObjectByPath("/cmis-demo");

String timeStamp = new Long(System.currentTimeMillis()).toString();
String filename = "cmis-demo-doc (" + timeStamp + ")";

// Create a doc
Map <String, Object> properties = new HashMap<String, Object>();
properties.put(PropertyIds.OBJECT_TYPE_ID, "cmis:document");
properties.put(PropertyIds.NAME, filename);
String docText = "This is a sample document";
byte[] content = docText.getBytes();
InputStream stream = new ByteArrayInputStream(content);
ContentStream contentStream = getSession().getObjectFactory().createContentStream(filename, Long.valueOf(content.length), "text/plain", stream);

Document doc = folder.createDocument(
           properties,
           contentStream,
           VersioningState.MAJOR);

System.out.println("Created: " + doc.getId());
System.out.println("Content Length: " + doc.getContentStreamLength());
System.out.println("Version label:" + doc.getVersionLabel());

// Now update it with a new version
if (doc.getAllowableActions().getAllowableActions().contains(org.apache.chemistry.opencmis.commons.enums.Action.CAN_CHECK_OUT)) {
   doc.refresh();
   String testName = doc.getContentStream().getFileName();
   ObjectId idOfCheckedOutDocument = doc.checkOut();
   Document pwc = (Document) session.getObject(idOfCheckedOutDocument);
   docText = "This is a sample document with an UPDATE";
   content = docText.getBytes();
   stream = new ByteArrayInputStream(content);         
   contentStream = getSession().getObjectFactory().createContentStream(filename, Long.valueOf(content.length), "text/plain", stream);          
   ObjectId objectId = pwc.checkIn(false, null, contentStream, "just a minor change");
   doc = (Document) session.getObject(objectId);
   System.out.println("Version label is now:" + doc.getVersionLabel());
}
```

When run, it outputs this:

```
Created: workspace://SpacesStore/d6f3fca2-bf9c-4a0e-8141-088d07d45359;1.0
Content Length: 25
Version label:1.0
Version label is now:1.1
Done
```

Comment: Thank You very much... I want to know one more thing like could we change the label as 2.0 instead of 1.1??

Comment: Yes, you'd just change the major flag from false to true, so you'd do this: ObjectId objectId = pwc.checkIn(true, null, contentStream, "this one is a major change");